# PageViewController (app presentation) for the first launch then tabBarViewController, Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, nsuserdefaults, uipageviewcontroller

I have a **PageViewController** with 3 views to present the app, on the last page I have a button linked with my **TabBarViewController**.
I would like to have only for the first launch, my 3 views of presentation and then for the next launched, start directly with my TabBarViewController.

How can I do it?
**Thanks!!!**

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

tabBarController :

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
  }
```

Button between page views and tabBar :

```
@IBAction func firstTime() {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "hasAppBeenLaunchedBefore")
    print(true)

}
```

AppDelegate :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    didFinishLaunchingOnce()


    return true
}

func didFinishLaunchingOnce() -> Bool
{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let hasBeenLauncherBefore = defaults.stringForKey("hasAppBeenLaunchedBefore")
    {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var exampleViewController: TabBarViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController

        self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        //print(" N-th time app launched ")
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var exampleViewController: OnboardingPager = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingPager") as! OnboardingPager

        self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        //print(" First time app launched ")
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "hasAppBeenLaunchedBefore")
        return false
    }
}
```

**Enjoy**